# How can extract numbers from a string to a list as individual elements in python?

Tags: python, string, list, extract, strip

I would like to extract the numbers from the below string element of a list of n length into a list in their original form:

```
list = ['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants']

output = [25, 1, 4, 101]
```

I'm quite new to regex so I've been trying with the following:

```
[regex.findall("\d", list[i]) for i in range(len(list))]
```

However, the output is:

```
output = [2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Is your list input correct? You've got a list which contains just a single item (a `str`) which _looks_ like a list. Or was it supposed to be `['25 birds', '1 cat', '4 dogs', '101 ants']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a +

you find all should have "\d+", not just "\d"

Answer (score 2):

We don't really need to use regex to get numbers from a string.

```py
lst = ['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants']
nums = [int(word) for item in lst for word in item.split() if word.isdigit()]
print(nums)
# [25, 1, 4, 101]
```

Equivalent without list comprehension:

```py
lst = ['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants']
nums = []
for item in lst:
    for word in item.split():
        if word.isdigit():
            nums.append(int(word))
print(nums)
# [25, 1, 4, 101]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
list_ = ['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants']
import re
list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', list_[0])))
```

**Output**:

```
[25, 1, 4, 101]
```

Also, avoid assigning variable names as `list`.

Comment: It didnt have to be split. re.findall finds all non overlapping matches in a string. re.findall('\d+',list_[0]) would have returned all 4 matches.

Comment: Aha, surely I didn't get the `re.findall('\d+')` but the complicated part was not my intention. Thank you for pointing out TBH !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to achieve this. I used `re.compile` given that it is a bit faster than calling `re` functions straight out of the module, if you have really long lists.

I also used `yield` and `finditer` since I do not know how long your lists will be, so this will provide some memory efficiency, given their lazy evaluation.

```
import re

def find_numbers(iterable):
    NUMBER = re.compile('\d+')
    def numbers():
        for string in iterable:
            yield from NUMBER.finditer(iterable)

    for number in numbers():
        yield int(number.group(0))

print(list(find_numbers(['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants'])))
# [25, 1, 4, 101]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import re

list_ = ['25 birds, 1 cat, 4 dogs, 101 ants']
output = list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', list_[0])))
print(output)
```

**output:**

```
[25, 1, 4, 101]
```

**Explanation:**

`re.findall` returns list of string where strings are scanned from left to right, matches are return in the order found.

`map` applies int to each item in list of string and returns map object

`list` Since map object is iterator, pass it as argument to factory method for creating list